# Calling setState from a function that was passed as props

Tags: reactjs, binding, state, setstate

I would like to modularize a large component so I can reuse some of it's parts.

Both times a list is rendered on which I can do operations on: updates my modals state so it closes, then launches a redux action with a server call.

So I would like to pass a function that defines the custom behaviour:

```
var handleSubmit = (name, description, author) => {

    if (inputsValidated(name, description)) {
        this.setState({ addingNewProject: false, errorMessage: '' });

        var payload = { name: name, date: new Date(), description: description, author: author},
            routeToPushAfter = `/app/users/${author._id || 'notsigned'}`,
            serverRoute = allRoutes.projectURL,
            type = 'project'

            this.props.postData(payload, routeToPushAfter, serverRoute, type);
    }

    else {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please fill out form' });
    }
}
```

Then pass this function to the component.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={main}>
            <DynamicList {...this.props} />
            <DynamicList {...this.props} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is: the this.setState is bound to the parent component. How could I pass a function with which I can modify the local state (without using Redux).

Thank you for any input!

Comment: you can use a [high order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: Instead of keeping the error message on the state you should pass the error message into the list as part of the props.  Yes this is the HOC concept.

Comment: I'm reading the HOC now, thanks. @robbymurphy, that would solve the errormessage, but not the addingNewProject Boolean that I need for the modal to open and close.

Comment: @DSz you would pass that in as well.  The HOC takes care of the state and passes it down as props to the inner components.

Comment: So I have to somehow trigger from the child component the state of the parent component, that then get's fed back to the child component? Is there be a more elegant version of this?

Answer (score -2):

You may bind the function to the component inside `DynamicList`'s constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  if (this.props.handleSubmit) {
    this.handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a band-aid.  It makes creates a tight coupling between the DynamicList and it's container.  The DynamicList should be "dumb" and simply accept props that specify how it should render instead of handling its own error state.  Especially since the function that is producing the error is outside of the DynamicList component.